# App Namespace Lost

Tags: namespaces, facebook-apps

I created an app then accidentally deleted it and when I tried to recreate it I got the message that the app namespace was already taken. Is it possible to get the same namespace?

Answer (score 1):

Once you delete an app you created on FB, you can't re-create it with same namespace. It is a bug in FB. Once I had same issue and when I tried to get hep from FB community help center, I found many people having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you manage to contact that developer and bribe him with beer or chocolate. :)

I don't think there is much you can do about it.  Much like someone taking your domain name,  the app namespace defines your application within Facebook - this is why it has to be unique.

Why don't you try placing a hypen `-` between words in your namespace.
For example:
`https://apps.facebook.com/sean-sekora`

Comment: You didn't answer his question.  He created it, not someone else.   I just ran into this myself.  I'm developing an app for a local gym, and had originally created the facebook app under my account.  I went and deleted the app, which no longer shows up for me, but when they login and try to create an app, it says taken.   What is strange is that if I log back in and create the app again, it's available for me, but not them.  I'll probably have them just register with a _ in the middle of the gym name but it's a pain.